# Charity wordpress template that works with CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to move our website from Drupal/CiviCRM to Wordpress/CiviCRM but understand that not all wordpress template will work with CiviCRM. Does anyone have a recommendation on the best charity wordpress template to use? We are a very small NFP and don't have money to spend on development.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume when you say charity template/theme you mean free. I don't think its likely that the general requirements of a charity would need particular things from a theme

Answer (score 1):

The default Wordpress theme seems to work fine and that is free. Unless you have any specific requirements, I'd stick with that.